# HTTP Status 404 - Building a JSF with Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jsf, http-status-code-404

So I am trying to do a tutorial in which I build with maven a project from cmd, then import it in eclipse, create a jsf with `hello world` message, but when i enter on `http://localhost:8080/helloworld2/home.jsf` i get the `404 not found` error.

This is my `HelloWorld` class

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
@ManagedBean(name = "helloWorld", eager = true)
public class HelloWorld {
    public HelloWorld() {
        System.out.println("HelloWorld started!");
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

This is the `home.xhtml`:

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>JSF Tutorial!</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            #{helloWorld.message}
        </body>
    </html>
```

I have deployed the .war file and then ran it on Tomcat. I may have not explained it very well, but any help is more than welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your home.xhtml is on
src>webapp

and your web.xml contains this should work

```
<!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/home.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
        <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Could I see the tutorial you are following?
And please post your web.xml code

Comment: I have a very similar example here [link](https://github.com/vladwoguer/JSF-Java-Server-Faces-Exemplo)
i also noted I wrote webapp>WEB-INF but what I really want to mean is webapp only. I edited my question.

Comment: this is the [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_first_application.htm) i am following

Comment: Is your home.xhtml under the webapp folder?

Comment: The tutorial is ok, try to follow the steps again. Sorry :(

Comment: Just a tip: you forgot to include the html doctype on your html    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">